# Kotlin replace isEmpty()&last() with lastOrNull() within a Collection

Tags: list, arraylist, collections, kotlin

I would like to use something like (code below), but I think that there must be a nicer solution with usage `lastOrNull()` instead of using `isEmpty` and `last()`

```
data class Entry(val x: Float, val y: Float)
```

---

```
var entries: MutableList<Entry> = ArrayList()
if(some) {
  entries.add(Entry(100f, 200f)
}
val foo = (if (entries.isEmpty()) 0f else entries.last().y) + 100f
```

Is there some better way like `entries.lastOrNull()?.y if null 0f`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can using Kotlin [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) `?:`, for example:

```
//   if the expression `entries.lastOrNull()?.y` is null then return `0f` 
//                                  v              
val lastY = entries.lastOrNull()?.y ?: 0f
```

for the expression in your code above, you can using [safe-call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) `?.let`/`?.run` to make your code more clearly, for example:

```
//val foo = if (entries.isEmpty()) 0f else entries.last().y + 100f else 100f

//             if no Entry in List return `0F`  ---v
val foo = entries.lastOrNull()?.run { y + 100 } ?: 0F 
//                            ^--- otherwise make the last.y + 100
```

Comment: My I ask why do you use run and not let there?

Comment: @ligi hi, `run` take a [receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions), `let` take the receiver  as a parameter. so if you use `let`, you must change the code as `?.let{it.y + 100}`. the `it` is an implicit variable for the parameter. you can choose which one you like.

Comment: Thanks - so many options for similar cases ;-) run/let/with/apply - still struggling when to use which - just think let reads a bit nicer/more natural - thanks for your feedback

Comment: @ligi yeah. but they are for different situation. `apply` will return the `receiver` rather than the result in lambda body. `with` is not suitable here.

Comment: Yea sure - here the question is only really between run and let - I think I still prefer let - just as it reads more natural "let it be this" - run does not really speak to me here - but still trying to figure out best practices

Answer (score 0):

If I've managed to understand you correctly, this will do the job:

```
val foo = if (entries.isEmpty()) 0f else entries.lastOrNull()?.y ?: 0f + 100f
```

Comment: the `entries.isEmpty()` expression is unnecessary. if it is not empty it always return `last.y + 100` otherwise return `0f`. and the `List` contains `Entry` rather than `Entry?`, there is no need to using `last?.y` here.

Comment: Nice remark. I've missed the fact that the list contains non-nullable entries. Thank's.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late, my bad network. Not at all. I only want you know that.